# How to find the CMYK or RGB value of a commercial paint color?

Tags: color, cmyk, color-conversion, rgb

I have a client who has chosen a paint color for their office and they want to carry that exact color onto everything from signage to website to business cards as their "brand color".

Is there any way I can get the color values from their paint chip in CMYK or RGB so I can ensure everything will display and print in the correct color and coordinate all of these things? They have contacted the paint store and the only info they were able to provide was the number of shots/oz of each color, which as far as I know is useless. Any suggestions?

Comment: Paint stores at least in my locality are equipped with spectrometers for color mixing purposes. Last time i asked for color matching  in the hardware store they gave me me a chip that had a **Lab** color as well  as some apectrographic info for future reference. Be careful though getting the color into RGB might have different primaries so it will look different under ambient light conditions of the office.

Comment: Do you have access to a Pantone Color Bridge book?  If not, the cheapest I've seen are on ebay.  Equipped with one of those you could find a Pantone solid colour, and a CMYK colour.

Comment: Visit another paint store? Benjamin Moore franchise store manager near me (Montreal, Canada) tells me they can do it as part of their OEM paint sample analyser. FWIW

Answer (score 1):

If your budget permits, you may wish to consider a color analyzer tool. A quick search using those terms results in devices with an extremely wide range of prices.

I was surprised to find one on [Amazon currently on sale](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01KKEMIF0) for US$50 that received good reviews.

These devices in general sample the light reflected from your sample and filter it to the base color plan, displaying or storing the data for your use.

[image: color analyzer device]